# react native app blinks for second and stops

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

when i make a build using react-native run-build the app builds successfully but it opens on my device ,blink and then close.I used the following package to change the name of my app and also i made another firebase project just to match the application id of my app and firebase project, using this package my app name change but this got the issue.

> npm install react-native-rename -g

can you please tell me what is the issue I am adding the paths of the files and what is changed in files

#### ios/podfile

```
target 'fetchtaxi' do
  # Pods for fetchtaxi
```

#### android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">fetchtaxi</string>
</resources>
```

#### android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.fetchtaxi">
```

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fetchtaxi"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

#### android/app/BUCK

```
android_build_config(
    name = "build_config",
    package = "com.fetchtaxi",
)

android_resource(
    name = "res",
    package = "com.fetchtaxi",
    res = "src/main/res",
)
```

#### package.json

```
"name": "fetchtaxi",
```

#### app.json

```
{
  "name": "fetchtaxi",
  "displayName": "fetchtaxi"
}
```

> The main thing I notice during writing this is MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java file is deleted and missing.

Comment: react-native-rename have some issue, I have used this before, it will delete your MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java, so before you rename your project, you have to copy these two to another place, after rename, copy back and change the content about apps name to new one(both file), it may be work.  I'm not sure if it could help.

Comment: yes i found the solution my self the package delete the folder containing those 2 files. I just copy those files and make fetchtaxi folder and paste those files